# Magento 2 grids slow

Tags: grid, magento2

On our Magento 2 store we have gained quite a few customer records (around 800.000) and orders (around 1.600.000). We are experiencing bad performance from the sales grid and customer grid pages. So, I decided to do some research on the sql queries and noticed the following.

The slowest query (around 10 secs) on the order grid was (without any filters):

SELECT
COUNT(DISTINCT main_table.entity_id)
FROM
`sales_order_grid` AS `main_table`
LEFT JOIN `ae_ec` AS `ec` ON main_table.entity_id = ec.ec_order_id
LEFT JOIN `amasty_mostviewed_pack_sales_history` ON amasty_mostviewed_pack_sales_history.order_id = main_table.entity_id LEFT JOIN `sales_order` AS `sales_order_table` ON main_table.entity_id = sales_order_table.entity_id

On the customer grid it was the following (around 7 seconds):

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `customer_grid_flat` AS `main_table`
LEFT JOIN `directory_country_region` AS `rct` ON rct.region_id=`main_table`.`billing_region_id`
LEFT JOIN `directory_country_region_name` AS `rnt` ON rnt.region_id=`main_table`.`billing_region_id` AND rnt.locale='en_US'
LEFT JOIN `amasty_rewards_rewards` AS `amrewards` ON main_table.entity_id = amrewards.customer_id AND amrewards.id IN (
SELECT MAX(id)
FROM amasty_rewards_rewards
GROUP BY customer_id)

I guess this is only for displaying the total number of orders. Also, the extra joins are not needed I think. They are added by the extension providers.Any advice if there is a (good) way of disabling the counts on the grids? 10 seconds improvement on loading time is huge for us.

Comment: I have some general suggestions. First, don't use flat mode for EAV entities like customer and catalog. Second, MySQL optimation like buffer and pool size, thread count, ...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using OpenSource or Adobe Commerce?

If you're using Adobe Commerce you can archive orders:

```
https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-admin/stores-sales/order-management/orders/order-archive.html?lang=en
```

This feature reduced the amount of orders in the order grid and will keep your site performant.

Unfortunately this feature is not available in the OpenSource version.

In that case it could be worth looking at a 3rd party module such as : https://amasty.com/order-archive-for-magento-2.html